# Newtonsoft JSON Error - Point to local machine and not server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm running into a problem with de-serializing a JSON object on the server and not on local machine.

I'm able to write the error and it keeps on saying 'Value cannot be null' and for some reason, it's pointing to the cs:line on my local machine and not on the server. The error comes back from CTS(JsonRequest)

It works fine on the local machine with no errors, but when it's move up to the server the error occurs.

Error Msg:

```
System.ArgumentNullException
Message : Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: value
StackTrace :    at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
```

Return JSON String:

```
{
  "requestContext": {
    "shipTo": "0000012345",
    "timeZone": "420",
    "langCode": "en"
  },
  "ID": "1234567",
  "deviceID": "abcdefgh-c633-ijkl-9080"
}
```

Code:

```
var JsonRequest = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(NewRequest, Formatting.Indented);
var JsonResponse = CTS(JsonRequest);
var Response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(JsonResponse);

public string CTS(string JsonData) {
    var sslPath = Server.MapPath("~/") + Properties.Settings.Default.CertPath + Properties.Settings.Default.CertName;
    try {
        X509Certificate2Collection certificates = new X509Certificate2Collection();
        var myCert = new X509Certificate2(sslPath, @ "NotYourPassword");
        certificates.Add(myCert);
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (a, b, c, d) => true;

        // Create web request
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(new Uri("https://somedomain.com"));

        request.ClientCertificates = certificates;
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentLength = JsonData.Length;

        using(var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream())) {
            string json = JsonData;
            streamWriter.Write(json);
            streamWriter.Flush();
        }

        // Web response
        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();

        // Get the response back
        using(var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream())) {
            var responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            return responseText;
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        WriteError.WriteErrorToFile(ex);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the code that is causing the issue.

Comment: Please add string of your json.

Comment: `value` is null at the time that `DeserializeObject` is called, when run on the server. There's no way for us to know why with the (lack of) code you've shown. It always shows the file name and line number of where it was compiled. The cs files are not on the server (presumably).

Comment: Code is provided.

Comment: My guess is the response on the server is empty. Is an error being logged? Could be an issue with certificate that is returning a 500 and the body is empty so it can't be deserialized. Side note might be good to try RestSharp or HttpClient they tend to be good if at handling strange environment bugs that might happen.

Comment: I was able to figure it out. It was not able to access the certificate, so it pushed out null for the value. I had to switch LoadUserProfile to true on IIS to have it read the certificate.